# Count the number of content flagged by logged in user

Tags: 7, users, flags

I want to get the number of items (content) flagged by the logged in user.

```
<?php
  $flag = flag_get_flag('flag1');
  print $flag->get_count($nid);
?>
```

The above line would display the total number of times that content is flagged. How can i get number of items flagged by the logged in user. Lets say user A has flagged Content 1, Content2 and Content 3. Then the output needed is something as:

Number of Items flagged by [current:user]: 3

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This work for me in normal block (no in views):

```
<?php
global $user;
$uid = $user->uid; //Logged in user ID
$result = db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flagging WHERE uid=:uid and fid=2", array(':uid' => $uid))->fetchField(); //fid = ID your flag
print $result ." flagged items";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work , untested:

```
$result = db_select('flag_content', 'fc')
->fields('fc', array('content_id'))
->condition('content_type', $flag->content_type)
->condition('uid', $user->uid)
->condition('fid', $flag->fid)
->execute();

$flagged = $result->fetchCol();
return array('content_flagged_by_user' => $flagged);
```

You could also try Rules integration with Flag

Comment: i will try this...however is it not possible to do so using Views

Comment: The "Views" keyword is not found in your question ... please edit it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Flag API function: [flag_get_user_flags()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!flag!flag.module/function/flag_get_user_flags/7)

Suppose you want to get number of times `node A` was flagged by current logged in user:

```
$flag = flag_get_user_flags('node', 'NID_OF_A');
```